# Integrating CKEditor into ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ckeditor, dom-events, ckeditor.net

I am currently working on implementing a CMS for a website. I have very minimal experience using Javascript, jQuery, C#, etc. I mostly deal with Java, SQL, and C++. My question is I have the CKEditor instance loaded on the page. I am able to load the HTML that I have stored in my database into the CKEditor window, but I cannot get the values that I have changed back out of CKEditor.

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Head1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" >
<%--Javascript funciton for Display Contents button--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetContents() {
        // Display the value of CKEditor into an alert
        alert(CKEDITOR.instances.CKEditor1.getData());
        //Have also tried alert(CKEDITOR.instances[CKEditor1].getData());
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="form1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
</CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
<%--Button that executes the command to store updated data into database--%>
<asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" 
    onclick="SaveButton_Click" />
<button type="button" onclick="GetContents()">Display Contents</button>
  
</asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve HTML
        HomePageHTML hp = HomePageHTMLAccess.GetHomPageHTML();
        //Does HTML exist?
        if (hp.HTML != null)
        {
            PopulateControls(hp);
        }
     }

    //Method to load html from database into webpage
    private void PopulateControls(HomePageHTML hp)
    {
        //Display html
        CKEditor1.Text = hp.HTML;
        
    }
    //Method to save the updated html into the database
    protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text1 = CKEditor1.Text;
        HomePageHTMLAccess.UpdateHomePageHTML(text1);
    }
}
```

I have tested and know that I am writing to the database from the `SaveButton_Click` method. One thing that I have noticed is that I can display a static alert message, such as `alert("message");` but no alert window pops up at all with either of the lines in my code.

Any help at all in getting this set up so that I can either write to my database using the class structure, or just in getting `GetContents()` to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Page_Load you should check `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` before writing the `Text` property of the `CKEditor` control, otherwise, on every post back (ie. button click), the control will have the same value from database. –

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Retrieve HTML
            HomePageHTML hp = HomePageHTMLAccess.GetHomPageHTML();
           //Does HTML exist?
           if (hp.HTML != null)
           {
              PopulateControls(hp);
           }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian, it worked like a charm. In case anyone else has this problem for the SaveButton_Click method add an if (Page.IsPostBack), without the exclamation mark, and close all of the code in it and it will work.

Comment: @tuckerjt07, on SaveButton_Click, Page.IsPostBack will always be true (the page is posted back by the button click, makes sense?). Also, please, accept the answer.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but for some reason it wouldn't work until I put that if statement in there.

Comment: `!Page.IsPostBack` This means you entered the page first time and loading for the controls if written in page load handler should be done first time only.